# Did Luffy travel the same path that Roger took to get into Raftel?

Tags: one-piece

I've been quite curious as to why some of the islands that Roger has travled into are also voyaged by the Straw Hat Pirates such as Skypiea, Mermaid Island, and Zou.

If I recall correctly, there are routes in Grand Line on which you can set sail by traveling on the path indicated by the log pose( A device that tells you the direction of next island from the current island).

Answer (score 1):

***SPOILER ALERT:
Don't read if you aren't up to speed with current episodes.***

I can think of two reasons.But before that i would like to mention few points:

1. One piece is greatly linked with Joyboy, D (the will of D) and of course Laugh Tale.
2. On Rogers journey he had instances where he was told someone(luffy) would come and change the world. He is the person Joyboy is waiting for. Or something like that.
3. After conquering the grand line there wasn't much time left for him (he was sick).
4. He and crew came to know about the void century. But again due to point 3 they couldn't do much about it. And at the time world government had too much power and control over people.

Also, Before I compare their journeys for you. Understand this:

- One piece/Laugh tale (and other things like will of D/Joyboy/Void Century/Marines )
  are the real deal and the goals of the Straw hat pirates and not retracing the path of Legendary Gol D Roger. Although they do want his title and treasure(We don't know what that is) and nothing else.

> Record of the Void Century 800 years ago, in the Wano Country, a clan of master stonemasons known as the Kozuki Family invented indestructible block shaped steles for the purpose of recording important history on them while preventing it from being destroyed. Those steles would become the Poneglyphs.

- Poneglyphs lead to a location. It's the path that either was created to stay hidden(from enemies and people) or to preserve something(op). It's obvious but i also say this because ODA said at current level Akainu can get to one piece in a year. But  he doesn't because that's not what marines wan't or they may not like what they will get in the end. (by marines i mean the ones at the top).
- Roger in ZOU said to Pedro "My time is limited.Listen,Everyone has their own turn". Most people misinterpret this as his message to Pedro. Noooooo, he just mentioned that it was his(Roger's) turn. Pedro figures out his role on his own in whole cake arc **and then** realizes what Roger meant. Roger isn't the kind who would tell anyone random what to do. Because he wouldn't like it himself being told what to do. Here,

   a. The scene is after reaching Laugh tale (means he knew everything and acquired everything by the time)  
   b. and after meeting Oda.

   c. He knew about Joyboy, his promise and that someone will come after 20 years. And change the world 
  **So, What Roger meant was that,he needs to make sure that the man of prophecy** (he has learned about via different sources) **reaches the Laugh tale.**
- Last point: Hence, When you see the bigger picture there are 3 characters to evaluate

1. Joyboy: The mystery man we don't know much about. Who is the origin for most of the mysteries in one piece. Was the one who created path to one piece with help of wano kuri.And apparently Roger admires him, possibly so does luffy. 
2.Roger: Who traveled most of his life(**13 yrs +1 year** apparently before his death) connecting pieces left by Joyboy. Known as pirate king (also thought to be his highest achievement). His, highest achievement is refining the path of grandline and making sure the man of prophecy reaches Laugh tale.  
 [image: picture 1 roger]

3. Straw hat Monkey D Luffy: The main protagonist of the story that has been changing the world since arc I. And probably will change the fate of the world when he finds one piece.

Now, with considering all the data from above and concluding , Your answer:

Yes luffy and roger are travelling the same paths. And its because of one of the 2 reasons.

1. After Roger conquered the grand line which took him 13+ years. Sailed again with Oden to provide a path to the man of prophecy (yours luffy) So, that he wouldn't have to invest as much time and effort as roger did. 
    In order to do this Roger traveled the grand line again in his last year alive. The only things mind blowing here is, Roger didn't knew which path luffy will take, so he travel the whole grand line that took him 13 years in 1 year. I mean he might know the path, and he probably wouldn't face much resistance like the first time but 13-1 ratio is still insane. (You might think he could have just helped in one path that luffy has been taking , but thats not an option here. Roger wouldn't leave his life's work to luck. He would rather die working). So, by this point Roger must have travelled Most of the "major" kingdoms/islands twice.
2. We have been told that there are multiple paths that you can take on grand line. See fig below.[image: grandline image] 
   If you look at this clearly you'll see that there are points that are common will travelling the grand line. Hence, if not any other island, Roger and luffy would have to travel these. So, sabaodi, fishman (and probably punk hazard) are a 100% possiblily. Roger went to wano and zou for/with oden Hence similarities there too. But there will be no explaination to Skypiea other than luck by chance.

   Unless for example, lets say there are 4 paths to traverse grand line. One luffy took, one for law probably, one for kid , One for others skiping the details. Roger could have chosen 1/2 islands(so unique that only few{deserving} can find the poneglyph) per route to say things like he said to luffy on the poneglyph in skypia. This would explain the one year too but still some things would be left to luck.

Edit: All in all, it was Rogers role to make it happen.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is **no**, he is isn't travelling the **exact** same path as Luffy.

We do know that Gol D. Roger travelled the world for ~14 years after he reached the **2nd** to last island, *Lodestar* (end of the Grand Line). We also know that he was ~39 years old when he reached Lodestar Island.

That means he most probably been to every single island in the world over his ~35 years as a pirate, assuming he became one at approximately the same age as Luffy.

**--ANIME SPOILERS AHEAD: INCLUDES Chapter 967 FROM MANGA--**

@Ashish Kumar: Your timeline is slightly wrong.

We don't know how long it took Gol D. Roger to get to Lodestar island. The year he did reach it (39 years ago), is the year Shanks was born.

After that it took him 13 years to finally find someone from Wano, Oden (26 years ago). So for 13 years he was just searching for someone who can:

- read the Road Poneglyphs
- knows where the last poneglyph was (Zou)

After Oden joined Roger Pirates it took them less than a year to travel to:

*Skypeia > Water 7 > Tequila Wolf > Sabaody Archipelago > Fish-man Island > Wano > Zou > Some Harbour > Laugh Tale* (Chapter 967).

Before reaching Laugh Tale, Roger did not know about:

- Void Century
- Meaning of the name D
- Use for ancient weapons. But Roger wouldn't be able to use them as he was dying and Poseidon (the mermaid princess) wouldn't be born for another 10 years.

After reaching Laugh Tale, Roger disbands his pirate crew and spends the last year of his life with Portgas D. Rouge.

So Luffy is **not** travelling the same exact path as Roger. But Roger had 13 year of exploring the new world and visited most islands, possibly even **all** the islands in the world.

> Sailed again with Oden to provide a path to the man of prophecy (yours
>   luffy) So, that he wouldn't have to invest as much time and effort as
>   roger did.

Roger couldn't possibly know about Luffy (or any other Joyboy) before Laugh Tale.

Comment: I understand i have a few errors in my timeline. But do explain to me, if `Roger couldn't possibly know about Luffy (or any other Joyboy) before Laugh Tale.` Then why did he make Oden write that he will guide reader of poneglyph's Journey.

Comment: There are a number of translations of Rogers/Oden's writing in Skypeia next to the poneglyph:
https://m.imgur.com/lDtErbK
https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5qQF.jpg

Basically it means that he was going to follow the poneglyphs to Laugh Tale. Doesn't necessarily mean that it was a message for Luffy, it was also the first poneglyph they found in person (not transcribed). He wanted to leave a message showing his resolve to reach the final island.

Comment: The messages from Joyboy are at Laugh Tale and on the poneglyph is in Fish-man island, Roger went there after Skypeia. Joyboy is part of the Void Century and poneglyphs are the only true records of that time (outside the top WG)

Only references we know that Roger was definitely waiting for someone are after he reached Laugh Tale. I think the first one is him discussing it with Whitebeard (576)

Even Oden on the way from Laugh Tale  (968) said that they should open up Wano before Joyboy returns. That was the reason Oden joined Roger's crew, to find the purpose of Wano and Kozuki clan.